# Docker WILL NOT Run on boot/reboot 18.04 LTS

Tags: docker, service

I am at the ends here, I have tried every possible thing I can think of or google in order to get docker to run on boot. this is what I have tried:
systemctl enable docker
systemctl enable docker.service

even my wings.service for docker in /etc/systemd/system wont run either when I enable it. Every time I reboot and type service docker status it resultls in

`● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com`

Adding - Even newly installed programs don't start on boot by default, example glances - I tried glances run, then tried `service glances status` resulting in not running/active

Comment: Does docker start when you start it manually? Is anything in the logs?

Comment: Is there a symlink to /lib/systemd/system/docker.service in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service

Comment: please post `journalctl -u docker | tail -100̀`

Answer (score 1):

There is a ticket tracking this Ubuntu issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker/+bug/1858441

The workaround suggested in the ticket is to simply run:

```
systemctl enable docker  # Start Docker on next reboot
systemctl start docker  # Start Docker now
```

Comment: OP indicated that they have run the enable docker command.